# Why is VimDiff so limited?

Tags: vim, vimdiff

With all the advanced editing capabilities of Vim, I find it hard to believe that VimDiff doesn't have a way of copying from/to right/left!! What else can a difftool be used for? Any idea? What are the capabilities of VimDiff?

Also, I don't even see a way of moving to the next/prev difference!!

Comment: The question "What are the capabilities of VimDiff?" logically *precedes* the question "Why is VimDiff so limited?"   :)    In any case, the only thing I really miss is the ability manually align diff regions when it gets confused.

Comment: Nice comment :-) Yeah, I admit I was too rude thinking that VimDiff doesn't support simple capabilities :D

Comment: But what do you mean by manually aligning diff regions? How would you control thta? And what difftool supports that?

Comment: By "manual aligning" I mean manually telling the diff engine that *this* line in file A corresponds to *that* line in file B. [BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/) supports it, and it's sometimes invaluable. Or to put it another way, when you need it and it's *not* there (which happens to me sometimes in Vim) it's maddening.

Comment: Oh, that would be great. I always thought of such a feature.

Comment: Definitely consider consulting `:help` before posting to SO.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Every thing is explained in the help ... (`do`, `dp`, `]c`, `[c`)

```
:h diff
```

`:h :h` is also your friend.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use `do` and `dp` for your copying needs; these represent 'put' from current window, and 'obtain' from the other window.  (This assumes a dual-split diff.)

For moving to next/prev difference, use `]c` and `[c` .

Here are the basic commands I use, with mnemonics where possible:

```
dp - 'put' the changes from the current window into the other window.
do - 'obtain' the changes from other window.
]c - Go to change after (ending/next bracket) -- move to the next difference.
[c - Go to change before(opening/previous bracket) -- move to the previous diff.
zo - 'open' a section of folded text.
zc - 'close' a foldable text section.
Ctrl-W+Ctrl W - (That's ^W twice.) Jump to the other window.
:diffupdate - updates diff based on changes .
```

Comment: thanks for this useful answer, I knew enough vimdiff to get by, but not the dp/do abbrevs nor ]c [c :)